# How to limit a view panning just inside an other View?

Tags: ios, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a subview (the red bar) laid inside a view. I want to limit the panning area inside the parent view and only absolutely horizontal or vertical. And, of course not outside of the parent view.

I did try some code that handle the panning event, but sometime I can drag the red bar out. Any suggestion?

```
-(void)handleMoveLineView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

CGPoint sPoint= [recognizer locationInView:self.groundView];

CGPoint newCenter = [recognizer translationInView:self.groundView];
NSLog(@"X0 = %f, Y0 = %f", newCenter.x, newCenter.y);
if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    beginX = recognizer.view.center.x;
    beginY = recognizer.view.center.y;
}

for (UIView *view in viewArrayGroundView) {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, sPoint)) {
        //Limit not out side parent view
        if (beginX + newCenter.x != view.frame.size.width /2) {
            newCenter = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width /2, beginY + newCenter.y);
        }
        //Limit top - since the redbar height is 3
        else if((beginY + newCenter.y < view.frame.origin.y + 3)){
            newCenter.y = view.frame.origin.y + 3;
        }
        //Limit bottom
        else if((beginY + newCenter.y > view.frame.size.height - 3)){
            newCenter.y = view.frame.origin.y - 3;
        }

    }
}       


[recognizer.view setCenter:newCenter];
NSLog(@"X = %f, Y = %f", newCenter.x, newCenter.y);
}
```

[image]

Comment: add sub view to your view and add pan gestures to that view.

Comment: The red line is actually a subview and it has pan gesture. I've already panned it. But the problem is I want to limit it inside the parent view.